# How to get mathematical model from a data set with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, modeling

I have some values imported from excel about the annual sell of a product, with 3 var:

*month, 
price, 
sold items*

I have seen how to plot a chart using *curve fitting tool* but I need to define a math expression that can describe the relation between these variables.

How can I do this in matlab? Is there any tool that can achieve this automatically. If you look at the chart should exist a way to use an approximation that can mime the behavior(maybe with spline functions or n-point-hermit), is enough one approximated expression of the model that for the 3 var replicates a similar graph if plotted.

Comment: Do you have any intuition as to what kind of function you want to model the data with or any indication as to what might make a good candidate function to model the data based on visual inspection?

Comment: @Paul no I haven't such intuition for this reason I'm looking for a way to compute it.

Comment: You might want to plot the data to see any trends.

Comment: [Generalized linear models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) are the best starting point for fitting models to such data.  You have to convert the categorical "month" variable into a numerical value and then do the fitting.  R has several built-in functions that do the job surprisingly well.

Comment: I have yet plotted a fitting 3D graph with matlab, I need a way to generate also an expression in function of these var. with the standard fitting that I know I have obtained only a polynomial interpolation expression that isn't in function of the 3 variables

Comment: Let $y$ = annual sell, and $x_1, x_2, x_3$ = month, price, items sold.  The best you can plot is $y$ vs $x_1,x_2$ or $y$ vs $x_2,x_3$ or $y$ vs $x_1,x_3$.  Try an affine model first, $y = A_0 + A_1 x_1 + A_2 x_2 + A_3 x_3$ and see how good your prediction accuracy is.  After that you can try changing the powers of the independent variables if that explains the data better.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee I have asked for a way to compute automatically exactly to avoid these kind of manual try and tests.

Comment: Unfortunately human knowledge is not yet at the stage where we can get a good model automatically without knowing anything about the data.  You best bet right now, if you have large amounts of data, is to fit a neural net.  But the tool depends on what you want: a good prediction or a plottable prediction.

Comment: I meant a regression tree (e.g., random forest) (not a neural net).  My approach would be to learn something about the data and then fit a linear model after creating new features of the form $x_1^2$, $x_1x_2$ etc.